# Creating a Filter Button in GridJS

Tags: gridjs

I am new to gridjs and am struggling to find a way to add filter buttons. I am looking to add dropdown selectors or buttons that will filter out entire rows if a specified value is not in a specified column.

For example, if I have this table:
|   Color  | Another header |
| -------- | -------------- |
| Blue     | Value1         |
| Green    | Value2         |
| Blue     | Value3

Is it possible within gridjs to create a filter dropdown that if you select blue, it would filter out all non-blue values and vice versa if you selected green?